# span in link with class

Tags: cakephp

I was messing around with the cakePHP link tag...
And, the span is located inside the link.

I know about escape => false, but seems to me, this doesn't really work.
The php part is embedded within the 'li' as below:

```
   <?php echo $this->Html->link($html->tag('span','Hello World'),
                                     array('controller'=>test,
                                           'action'=>index),
                                     array('class' => 'class_b'),
                                     array('escape' => false)
                                ) 

    ?>
```

My problem here is, the 'span' tag isn't 'eliminated' from the view. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, but... if you don't want the span tag included in the view, why are you including it in the $this->Html->link()?

Comment: Because, inside my css file...I set the text-properties of Hello World inside span (wrapped in link) to be..whatever I defined....

Comment: That makes sense about using a link inside a span.  But, is there any way you could rephrase the question?

Comment: I already edited my question...My problem here is, the span tags are still visible in the browser, although with the escape=>false added to the code.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to have a *span* in the browser, don't type "*span*" in the link code, (unless you are using CSS to hide the span from the user in the browser.)

Answer (score 5):

It's rather simple

```
<?
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('span',__('News',true)),array('controller'=>'news','action'=>'index'),array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'news'));
?>
```

you just need to add third parameter to Html link `escape=>false`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you might be looking for, then:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link(
             $this->Html->tag('span', 'Hello World.', array('class' => 'class_b')),
             array(
                 'controller' => 'test',
                 'action' => 'index'
             )
         );
?>
```

Found in this reference (near the bottom of the page):

1. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1442/link

Comment: urmmm...this results in [span class = 'class_b']Hello World[/span]...still, the span tags are visible...I've tried your solution before..that won't work...

Comment: Well, I wouldn't waste too much of your time trying to use the CakePHP link HTML helper, then.  It's easier just to use straight HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching answer and for me works this piece of code:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->tag('span', 'Hello world', array('class' => 'class_a')),
    array('controller' => 'test', 'action' => 'index'),
    array('escape' => FALSE)
  ); ?>
```